# Create 2 directory list in the same layout

Tags: android, listview, layout

How can i create 2 directory lists in the same layout? 
One to show file and folder from FTP server and the other to show local file/folder.

Edit:
I can put arrayadapter to Listview now with this line:
**listView.setAdapter(adapter);**
So I think I can create more directory list in the same layout.
But when I run the app,  click on folder, no effect. Here is all my code.

```
public class FileChooser extends ListActivity {
    private File currentDir;
private FileArrayAdapter adapter;
private TextView myPath;
ListView listViewLocal;
ListView listFtp;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myPath = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.path);
    listViewLocal = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listlocal);
    //listFtp = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.);
    currentDir = new File("/sdcard/");
    fill(currentDir);
}
private void fill(File f)
{
    File[]dirs = f.listFiles();
     //this.setTitle("Current Dir: "+f.getName());
     myPath.setText("Location: " + f.getName());
     List<Option>dir = new ArrayList<Option>();
     List<Option>fls = new ArrayList<Option>();
     try{
         for(File ff: dirs)
         {
            if(ff.isDirectory())
                dir.add(new Option(ff.getName(),"Folder",ff.getAbsolutePath()));
            else
            {
                fls.add(new Option(ff.getName(),"File Size: "+ff.length(),ff.getAbsolutePath()));
            }
         }
     }catch(Exception e)
     {

     }
     Collections.sort(dir);
     Collections.sort(fls);
     dir.addAll(fls);
     if(!f.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("sdcard"))
         dir.add(0,new Option("..","Parent Directory",f.getParent()));
     adapter = new FileArrayAdapter(FileChooser.this,R.layout.file_view,dir);
     listViewLocal.setAdapter(adapter);
     //this.setListAdapter(adapter);
}
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    Option o = adapter.getItem(position);
    if(o.getData().equalsIgnoreCase("folder")||o.getData().equalsIgnoreCase("parent directory")){
            currentDir = new File(o.getPath());
            fill(currentDir);
    }
    else
    {
        onFileClick(o);
    }
}
private void onFileClick(Option o)
{
        Toast.makeText(this, "File Clicked: "+o.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Hi gunar, I mean "How can i create 2 directoriy lists in the same layout?"
And I think I have fixed it. But new problem appear as my update question above.

Comment: you are going to need 2 lists